# I am interested in Sociobiology. Which academic field should I study?

Tags: sociobiology

I like to study Sociobiology and evolutionary psychology. Which academic fields concentrate on these sciences in bachelor and master degrees?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about career advice, not biology.

Comment: So to continue with what Remi B says, of course it is going to require quite a bit of chemistry for it all. Chemistry in sociobiology distinguished areas among each other, where even nuclear reading make a distinction for it all.

Comment: This could be reworded to be more oriented toward field of study/self education advice rather than career advice, It may be more acceptable then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What fields are sociobiology and evolutionary psychology?**

[Sociobiology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociobiology) (aka. social evolution) is a subfield of evolutionary biology.

[Evolutionary psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_psychology) is a subfield of both evolutionary biology and psychology. Evolutionary psychology is, for the moment, very theoretical without much (if any) empirical testing. For this reason, not only natural scientists 
 and social scientists work on the subject but some philosophers have also contributed (such as [Daniel Dennett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Dennett) for example).

**How to become a researcher in one of these fields?**

Biology.SE is not BiologyCareerAdvice.SE. We have way too few information about you to give reliable career advice anyway. Also, I am not trained in any way to give you carrer advice.

That being said, a priori, start with a Bachelor in Biology and follow up with a master in Evolutionary Biology. Because evolutionary psychology is very inter disciplinary, I would personally advice to go with whatever broad field of study attracts you most. If you are more into psychology than biology, please go with psychology. If you are more into philosophy than biology, then go into philosophy.

**Short intro to evolutionary biology**

For a very short intro course to evolutionary biology, you can have a look at [evo101](https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01) by UC Berkeley.

Comment: Remi. Please discourage people looking for career advice on here.

Comment: @TheLastWord Yes, I think you're right. I added `Biology.SE is not BiologyCareerAdvice.SE. We have way too few information about you to give any reliable career advice. Also, I am not trained in any way to give you carrer advice. `